# Beautifulsoup AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html code:

```
<div>
    <span class="test">
     <span class="f1">
      5 times
     </span>
    </span>

    </span>
   </div>

<div>

</div>

<div>
    <span class="test">
     <span class="f1">
      6 times
     </span>
    </span>

    </span>
   </div>
```

I managed to navigate the tree, but when trying to print I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Python code working:

```
x=soup.select('.f1')
print(x)
```

gives the following:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[<span class="f1"> 19 times</span>]
[<span class="f1"> 12 times</span>]
[<span class="f1"> 6 times</span>]
[]
[]
[]
[<span class="f1"> 6 times</span>]
[<span class="f1"> 1 time</span>]
[<span class="f1"> 11 times</span>]
```

but `print(x.prettify)` throws the error above. I am basically trying to get the text between the span tags for all instances, blank when none and string when available.

Comment: shouldn't it throw: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'prettify' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` returns a list of the results, regardless if the result has 0 items.  Since `list` object does not have a `text` attribute, it gives you the `AttributeError`.

Likewise, `prettify()` is to make the html more readable, not a way to interpret the `list`.

If all you're looking to do is extract the `text`s when available:

```
texts = [''.join(i.stripped_strings) for i in x if i]

# ['5 times', '6 times']
```

This removes all the superfluous space/newline characters in the string and give you just the bare text.  The last `if i` indicates to only return the `text` if `i` is not `None`.

If you actually care for the spaces/newlines, do this instead:

```
texts  = [i.text for i in x if i]

# ['\n      5 times\n     ', '\n      6 times\n     ']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<div>
    <span class="test">
     <span class="f1">
      5 times
     </span>
    </span>
    </span>
   </div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="test">
     <span class="f1">
      6 times
     </span>
    </span>
    </span>
   </div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
aaa = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'f1'})
for i in aaa:
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
5 times
6 times
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using `.findAll` method and loop over matched spans.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for span in soup.findAll("span", class_="f1"):
    if span.text.isspace():
        continue
    else:
        print(span.text)
```

The `.isspace()` method is checking whether a string is empty (checking if a string is True won't work here since an empty html span cointans spaces).